# Additional MFA for sensitive apps in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

We have received a requirement from client where they want MFA to be imposed mandatorily incase a user accesses certain sensitive applications. Ex., I login to myapps and am prompted for MFA and land on the desired page. On accessing a certain app from myapp I should be again prompted for MFA(irrespective of how long it has been since I logged in).
With conditional access policies, though I attach 'Require MFA' on those applications, it doesn't prompt for MFA if I am already logged in and have a session.
Any pointers as to how to achieve the intended functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this, if the session of the user is existing, it will not re-enforce the MFA auth.

So if you want the re-auth with MFA, you must need to clear the session, the closest way is to leverage the [sign-in Frequency policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime), but you can only [set it to `1 hour` at least](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime#policy-1-sign-in-frequency-control), after one hour, the user will be prompted to sign in again. Before enabling Sign-in Frequency, make sure other reauthentication settings are disabled in your tenant. If `Remember MFA on trusted devices` is enabled, be sure to disable it before using Sign-in frequency.

Comment: Thanks, have enabled the setting. Will update on the results.